# Which library to install for openGL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

Do i need to install GLUT also if i already have installed freeglut msvc package with visual studio 2010  on my windows 7 32 bit system ?. I am confused whether to install GLUT or freeglut as some sites refer to use GLUT, some for freeglut. Can anyone suggest the main library which is to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: GLUT is just a separate library, it is not required for OepnGL at all. The opengl libraries are deployed with the OS and/or the graphics drivers. On windows, there is microsoft's opengl32.dll (with OpenGL 1.1 support that is part of the windows API), and ICDs (installable client drivers) which come with the graphics drivers and allow one to use modern, hw-accelerated OpenGL via the extenstion mechanism - the application still links against microsoft's DLL.

To GLUT itself. There is the [GLUT specification](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/glut-3.spec.pdf) which defines the GLUT API. There are different *implementations* for this API. GLUT is kind of old, and the SGI GLUT versions can be considered abandoned. The only GLUT implementation in active development today (as far as I know) is freeglut - so if you have installed it, you don't need any other.

Comment: but if installing freeglut is enough, when i am using a code having glew as header file the compiler cannot find it.

Comment: @dishap: glew is another matter entirely. If you use glew, you have to install the glew libraries, too. But that again is not part of OpenGL.